# Unable to execute a command if it contains spaces using java

Tags: java, linux

Issue:- If the executable command contain's any spaces then **System.exec** is omitting the string content after the first space.

For example:- if command="**/opt/GUIInstaller/installers/abc def gh.bin**"
Then java is executing command up-to **/opt/GUIInstaller/installers/abc** only and resulting a error like  **java.io.IOException: "/opt/GUIInstaller/installers/abc": error=2, No such file or directory**

```
protected void launch(final String command) 
{
    try 
    {
        if(command.contains("null"))
        {
            logger.error("Installer is not located in the specified folder: "+command);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        runTime.exec(command);
    }
    catch (IOException ioException) {
        logger.error(ioException.getMessage(), ioException);
    }
}
```

Is I am doing any mistake, please help me to solve this issue.

Environment:- Java7 update9 + RHEL6

Comment: Try `"/opt/GUIInstaller/installers/abc\\ def\\ gh.bin"` to escape the spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the javadocs of `Process#exec()`, `exec(String)` simply splits the given command string into tokens via `StringTokenizer`. If you do that job jourself by passing tokens to `exec()`, spaces in there are no problem:

```
runTime.exec(new String[] {"/opt/GUIInstaller/installers/abc def gh.bin", "--param1=foo"});
```

Comment: Even the solution is working, installer is not launched(I mean GUI window not appeared), if I tried it manually I am able to launch the installer window, even I check the process output its not giving any error. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: At-least let me know **--param1=foo** argument what it will do

Comment: Oh. This is just some random commandline parameter to illustrate how you'd specify those. If your command doesn't take any parameters, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
if(command.contains(" ")){command.replace(" ","\\ ");}
```

before the runTime.exec(command);

This basically just replaces spaces with escaped spaces..

Edit:
Or to make it smoother try to execute this

```
runTime.exec(command.replace(" ","\\ "));
```

without adding the aforementioned line..

Comment: You could probably do away with the if statement there, if there's no space the replace will silently do nothing.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that after posting. That's why I edited it. Thanks for your notice though ;)

Comment: `"\ "` is not an acceptable Java string literal. If you need a backslash in a string, you must escape it.

Comment: @kgopi Listen to creinig's advice, that's the correct one. Don't let `Runtime.exec` parse your command line.